# Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 - REST API (node & express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest, express

I just start to learn REST API using node and express. I want to read and write a file using APIs.
But this error comes out when I use postman to hit the API. But my browser shows the data perfectly. I don't understand how to solve this error.

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Web development\api-dairy\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)
    at parse (C:\Web development\api-dairy\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
    at C:\Web development\api-dairy\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\Web development\api-dairy\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Web development\api-dairy\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Web development\api-dairy\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

My code: server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const data = require('./data');

app.use(express.json())

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.send('hello world')
})

app.get("/api/student",(req,res)=>{

    //when use promise resolve, access data by then
    data.getStudent()
    .then(data=>{
        res.send(data);
    })
  
})

app.post('/api/student',(req, res)=>{
    const student = req.body;
    data.getStudent()
    .then(students=>{
        students.push(student)
        // all students rewrite here.
        data.insertStudent(students)
        .then(newStudent =>{
            //newStudent is the response of resolve
            res.send(students)
        })
    })
   
})

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, ()=>{
   console.log(`listing port no ${port}`) 
});
```

another module (data.js)

```
const fs = require('fs');

const getStudent = ()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        fs.readFile('./db.json', 'utf-8',(err, data)=>{
            // console.log(data);
            //JSON.parse convert the string data to js obj 
            const student = JSON.parse(data);
            resolve(student);
        })
    })
    
}

const insertStudent = (students) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
             fs.writeFile('./db.json',JSON.stringify(students),(err)=>{
                resolve("ok");
             })
        })


}

module.exports.getStudent = getStudent;
module.exports.insertStudent = insertStudent;
```

Database file (db.json)

```
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "rahim", "class": "7" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "karim", "class": "8" },
  { "id": 3, "name": "jahim", "class": "9" },
  { "id": 12, "name": "lahim", "class": "7" },
  { "id": 14, "name": "lahim", "class": "7" },
  { "id": 21, "name": "lahim", "class": "7" },
  { "id": 11, "name": "bahim", "class": "7" },
  { "id": 11, "name": "bahim", "class": "7" }
]
```

Comment: Maybe your content type is not JSON ?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw db.json file is my content. Hopefully, it writes in JSON format.

Comment: No no, I'm talking about the post man

Comment: So you only see the error when using Postman? For which route? If it's the POST route, what data are you sending? Can you show a screenshot from Postman?

Comment: This is the classic "you're not getting (or setting) JSON" error. Take that `const student = JSON.parse(data);` and uncomment that `console.log(data)`. What's in it? Also, don't cut off your error: show the full stack trace because you've cut off exactly the part that tells us (and you) which file and line of code in that file are the problem.

Comment: Also, please make sure you copy / paste the error message exactly as it appears. Your error message in the question identifies a plain space character as the unexpected token which is not invalid at all

Comment: Your `db.json` file most likely has a [byte-order-mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start which would make it invalid JSON

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I add the full error message.

Comment: In postman, use `raw` and `JSON` as the body type. @Md.Al-aminSahed https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#raw-data

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you first didn't parse the data and then push, change the post request and then try

```
app.post('/api/student',(req, res)=>{
    const student = req.body;
    data.getStudent()
    .then(jsonStudents=>{
        const students = JSON.parse(jsonStudents)
        students.push(student)
        // all students rewrite here.
        data.insertStudent(students)
        .then(newStudent =>{
            //newStudent is the response of resolve
            res.send(students)
        })
    })
   
})
```

Comment: `data.getStudents()` already parses the JSON